# Testing output from event listener in Angular service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is a problem that's been stuming me for a few days. Plunkr with code sample is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QHJCyKfM2yFyCQzB68GS?p=preview

Basically, I have a service factory that is listening for an event and returning a value.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on("myEvent", function(args, value) {
    $scope.myEventCalled = true;
  });
});

app.factory('myService', function($rootScope){
  var mysvc = {}
  mysvc.testVar = true
  $rootScope.$on('otherEvent', function(args, value){
    $rootScope.rootCalled = true;
    mysvc.testVar = false;
  });
  return mysvc

});
```

My test is:

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var svc = null

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  it('should be able to see settings in service', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    inject(function($httpBackend, myService) {
      svc = myService
    })

    expect(svc).toBeDefined();
    expect(svc.testVar).toBe(true);
  }));

  it('should invoke otherEvent when  "otherEvent" broadcasted in service', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    inject(function($httpBackend, myService) {
      svc = myService
    })

    $scope.$broadcast('otherEvent');
    expect(svc.testVar).toBe(false);
  }));
});
```

The first test passes but the second test fails, as it's not able to trigger the event and access the modified value.

I get how to test this with a controller, but verifying that the value has been changed from a service has escaped me. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myService` is listening on `$rootScope`, but in your second test the event is broadcasted on `$scope`. Since `$broadcast` dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes and their children, it will not reach `$rootScope`.

Change it to this in the second test and it will work:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('otherEvent');
```

However, when testing a controller it's recommended to use mocked versions of its dependencies and only test the controllers own functionality in isolation. In the same fashion each service should get its own spec.